# Did anyone worked on CWE 601 veracode flaws

Tags: veracode

Did anyone in this community worked on veracode flaws CWE 601 for
1. Insufficient input Validation.
2. URL redirecting to untrusted site.

I tried Google but I didn't get any proper solution to my question. Can anyone of you provide me the basic idea for the above two questions.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on CWE 601 issues where we were assigning URLs to variables and Veracode was detecting the same as a flaw.

I used encodeURI() method to wrap the parameters that were being passed and as this method encodes all the parameters, it diminishes the risk of phishing. Thus Veracode doesn't detect it as a flaw.

This will work for JavaScript files.